# What R package is the "Error" function in?

Tags: r

I'm trying to call the `Error()` function but it says `could not find function "Error"`. I [checked the docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3) and Error does not seem to be a part of R base package. This is a very hard function to search for because "Error" is a very overloaded word. What package is Error() in? For context, I'm running an anova. I'm pretty sure that this isn't a user defined since I see multiple tutorials referencing it without defining.

EDIT:
Here are the tutorials:
https://datascienceplus.com/two-way-anova-with-repeated-measures/ , http://personality-project.org/r/r.guide/r.anova.html#withinone (look at usages of Error() in within sujects/repeated measures anova)

EDIT2:
Here is the model answer from the tutorial. There does not seem to be any information about how the 'Error' function is defined or where it comes from:

model <- aov(wm$iq ~ wm$condition + Error(wm$subject / wm$condition))

Comment: Maybe more experienced users will have an answer off the top of their heads, but it would be helpful for us to see snippets from the tutorials that reference this function so that we can have some context about how this function is being used.

Comment: Agreed with Weihuang. I know of the `stop` and `tryCatch` functions.

Comment: added the tutorials to the question

Answer (score 2):

The Error() in this case is specifying the error term for the `aov` function. It's a parameter passed to the function `aov()` and thus is not a function on its own. I've also tried searching for `Error` using the package `sos`, which yields 0 results:

```
# install.packages("sos")
library(sos)
results <- findFn("Error")
filtered_results <- results[results$Function == 'Error']
nrow(filtered_results)
```

Output:

`[1] 0`

You might want to read [this Cross Validated post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60108/how-to-write-the-error-term-in-repeated-measures-anova-in-r-errorsubject-vs-e) on how to set the Error term within the aov() function.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but if it's not a function why does it have parentheses/take arguments like a function?

Comment: Are you just following along with the tutorials and using their code exactly as it's shown there?

Comment: sorry I pressed enter too soon, I rephrased my comment

Comment: I think it has to do with the arguments the aov function takes in. I looked a bit at the source code on GitHub but didn't really understand it too well. I'm not that knowledgeable about ANOVAs to be honest. You could try asking on Cross Validated and see if anyone can explain it more.